# postgres convert char to datetime

Tags: regex, postgresql

ok guys, im trying to convert char based on text filename. the name extracted using regex. it works perfectly until meet this date August21st.

```
select to_char(
to_date(
     regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_replace(
                        substr('UserAndMasterPlanPerAugust21st2015.txt',21),
                        '.txt',''),
                    'rd','-'),
                'th','-'),
            'nd','-'),
        'st','-'),
    'MonthDD-YYYY'),
'YYYYMMDD')::integer
```

that code will produce this errors.

```
ERROR:  invalid value "Augu-21st" for "Month"
DETAIL:  The given value did not match any of the allowed values for this field.
```

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid value "Augu-21st" for "Month"
SQL state: 22007
Detail: The given value did not match any of the allowed values for this field.

i expect the result for this date is 
    20150821

i already know the problem is on 'st' because there are two 'st', i just trying the best way to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Is it just this one? Or are you going through list of filenames?

Comment: If your filename prefix is consistent remove the "UserAndMasterPlanPer" first and then you're good

Comment: the prefix is consistent the only thing that changed is the date. is all good with another date. the problem comes when there are two 'st' ex: August21st

Comment: Strip off prefix and .txt then do to_char(to_date('August21st2015", "MonthDDthYYYY"), "YYYYMMDD")

Comment: if you take a look the code above i already did the substr that will leave only the "August21st2015" part. my question is my regex will be conflict coz of there are two 'st' there and my code grab the first 'st'. and it will become Augu-21st hence my target is August21-2015

Comment: Fixed your issue. Check out the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may use another regular expression, I suggest you to try to use this one to remove ordinals from a date like:

```
(?<=[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)
```

[example here](https://regex101.com/r/gJ9vE0/1)

You only need to escape it to postgres dialect...

Comment: I think removing the prefix to the date first would be optimal. If his filename has a number and those matching values it'll catch that instead of the date

Comment: With this expression you are going to remove only ordinals and not other parts like auguST

Comment: User44theoryMasterPlanPerAugust22nd2015..... will be caught on the name is what i'm saying. That's why i asked if he's going through a list of random names.

Comment: That's a good point.... I didn't think about it... I assumed that the pattern was regular...

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion. i tried this regexp_replace('August21st2015', '(?:[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)', '-') and get this "August2-2015" it missed the 1. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I stripped the date from the string then casted to a date in the format that it is currently in. You then convert to char with the format that you want. CHEERS!

```
select to_char(
 to_date(
      substring('UserAndMasterPlanPerAugust21st2015.txt'
                 from 21 for length('UserAndMasterPlanPerAugust21st2015.txt')-24
               ), 'MonthDDthYYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD');
```

The purpose of the -24 is because I only want to move to the right the number of spaces that the date is. If the total length is n and I start from 21 that means i have n-20 characters left. I want to remove the .txt as well so move 4 less spaces. therefore I want to move from 21 -> to length of the string-24.

Comment: thx for the response but it got errors ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 1: ...bstring('UserAndMasterPlanPerAugust21st2015.txt', from 20 fo...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 76

Comment: I opened a fiddle doing it now one sec

Comment: wow it worked like a charm. btw what is the purposes of '-24' it still okay without it?

Comment: already kind sir but i need 15 points to get the upvote publicily. btw what the purpose of 'th' on this date format MonthDDthYYYY ?

Comment: The purpose of th is the date format in postgres. What you have to do is tell it the exact format in order for it to comprehend. In this case 22st\rd\nd etc is covered by the DDth format

Comment: thanks for your explanation. im not the one who upvoted my own questions its done by stack. and i already upvote your answer and i need 15points to show my upvote for your question.